# Find stationary points of $f(x,y) = (6 - x - y)x^2y^3$

Tags: analysis, systems-of-equations, stationary-point

I am stuck in the middle. I need to find stationary points of function from title. I managed to differentiate and create system of equations but I have no idea how to proceed with this.

$f_x(x,y) = xy^3(12 - 3x - 2y)$

$f_y(x,y) = x^2y^2(18 -3x - 4y)$

Part below made me stuck:

$\Bigg\{\begin{array}{c}xy^3(12 - 3x - 2y) = 0\\x^2y^2(18 -3x - 4y) = 0\end{array}$

I am looking for your help.

Comment: Can you think of any easy answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, If $x=0$ or $y=0$, you have a solution, so every point on the coordinate axes is a stationary point of $f$. If $x\ne 0$ and $y \ne 0$ the only solution is found solving the linear system $12-3x-2y=0, \quad 18-3x-4y=0$. so, the solutions are

1. $(0,t), \quad t \in \mathbb{R}$
2. $(t,0), \quad t \in \mathbb{R}$
3. $(2,3)$

Comment: So in such situation when I have for instance $xy(x+1) = 0$, $x = 0 \lor y = 0 \lor (x+1) = 0$, if x or y equals 0, it makes whole expression equal 0 and only option I should suspect to be stationary points are cases when $x \ne 0$ and $y \ne 0$?

Comment: @KasataAta Not exactly... It would depend on the other equation. In the case you presented, taking the first equation, we get $x=0 \vee y=0 \vee 12-3x-2y=0$. As it turns out, if $x=0$ or $y=0$ the second equation also holds, we take note of those soluitons (1. and 2.) and  concentrate on the remaining part (the linear system).

Comment: So, correct me if I am wrong, but first two solutions are lines in coordinate system, and third solution is the result of solving system of x and y not equal 0?

Comment: @KasataAta Yes, solving the system for solutions with $x \ne 0$ and $y\ne 0$ is the same as solving the linear system and you end up with two straight lines (1. and 2.) and a point (3.).

Comment: Now I get it. Thanks. One more question. If I will proceed with this and try to calculate extremas, so I will need $f_(xx)$, $f_(xy)$, $f_(yx)$ and $f_(yy)$ and then I will prepare a hessian matrix, what should I do with these $(0, t)$ and $(t, 0)$?

Comment: For the points in the axes, the second order criteria (Hessian matrix) may reveal inconclusive. If you look at the signal of $f$ in the whole plane, you will immediately be able to classify those stationary points.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98302/discussion-between-kasata-ata-and-pierrecarre).